# Reading in multiple srt files

Tags: r

I'd like to read in multiple srt files in R.  I can read them into a list but I need to load them in sequentially by the way they were created in the file directory.

I'd also like to make a column to tell which file they come from.  So I can tell which data came from file 1, file 2.. etc.

I can read them in as a list; but the files are names like "1 - FileTest"; "2 - FileTest", "#10 FileTest",... etc

This then loads the list like 1, 10, 11... etc.  Even though if I arrange the files in my file directory file 11 was created after 9 for instance.  I should just need a parameter for them to load sequentially so then when I put them in  dataframe they show in chronological order.

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path=path,  
                        pattern = "*.srt", 
                        full.names = TRUE)

Files <- lapply(list_of_files, srt.read)

Files  <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(Files),  byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The files load in but they don't load in chronological order it is difficult to tell what data is associated with which file.

I have approximately 150 files so being able to compile them into a single dataframe would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider extracting meta data of the files with [`file.info`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html) (includes created/modified time, file size, owner, group, etc.). Then `order` that resulting data frame by created date/time, and finally import `.srt` files with ordered list of files:

```
raw_list_of_files <- list.files(path=path,  
                                pattern = "*.srt", 
                                full.names = TRUE)

# CREATE DATA FRAME OF FILE INFO
meta_df <- file.info(raw_list_of_files)

# SORT BY CREATED DATE/TIME
meta_df <- with(meta_df, meta_df[order(ctime),])

# IMPORT DATA FRAMES IN ORDERED FILES
srt_list <- lapply(row.names(meta_df), srt.read)

final_df  <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(srt_list),  byrow=TRUE),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```